# How can I get alert(true) after ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How are you?
This is only html, css, jquery project, not node.js project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var flag = false;

      $("button").click(function () {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";

        setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "demo_test.txt",
            success: function (result) {
              $("#div1").html(result);
              flag = true;
            }
          });
        }, 3000)

        alert(flag);
      });
      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Get External Content</button>
  <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
  <div id="div2">
    <h3>My text area.</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="div1">
    <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to call ajax with sync, so I used `async: false`.
How can I get alert(true) after ajax call?
Please help me in this field. Thank you.

Comment: It's still false in this case because the code is still running while you waiting on the timeout.

Comment: I want to get the alert after ajax finished, but I get the alert in the first.
I really want async ajax calling. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Just put the alert inside the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.ajaxComplete()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) to have some code executed when an ajax resquest is completed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var flag = false;
      
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        alert(flag)
      })

      $("button").click(function () {
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";

        setTimeout(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1",
            success: function (result) {
              $("#div1").html(result.name);
              flag = true;
            }
          });
        }, 3000)
      });
      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Get External Content</button>
  <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">
  <div id="div2">
    <h3>My text area.</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="div1">
    <h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```